# context free grammar ambiguous?

Tags: context-free-grammar, ambiguous-grammar

For the following context free grammar:

```
S --> (S) | SS | A

A --> a | A,A | E        (E is the empty string)
```

The formal definition is:

```
G=(V,T,P,S)

V={A,S}

T={E;a; ( ; ) ; , }

S=S

P:
S --> (S)
S --> SS
S --> A
A -->a

A -->A,A

A --> E    (E is the empty string)
```

How do i know if this grammar is ambiguous or not?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If it were ambiguous, it would suffice that you find a word that parses in multiple different ways. To prove that it is not ambigous, you might be able to use a more general proof and prove that this is a special case, of you could build a proof by induction based on some property of set of generated words.

See for an (albeit complicated) example [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2320/how-to-prove-that-a-grammar-is-unambiguous/2329#2329).